# strip() regex replacement clarification

Tags: python, regex

I am working on the regex replacement for strip() program from the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python textbook and, since I had no idea how to even begin, I opted for Stack Overflow and found a thread with the following code :

```
#!python3
import re

respecchar = ['?', '*', '+', '{', '}', '.', '\\', '^', '$', '[', ']']


def regexstrip(string, _strip):
    if _strip == '' or _strip == ' ':
        _strip = r'\s'
    elif _strip in respecchar:
        _strip = r'\'+_strip'
    print(_strip) #just for troubleshooting 
    re_strip = re.compile('^'+_strip+'*(.+)'+_strip+'*$')
    print(re_strip) #just for troubleshooting 
    mstring = re_strip.search(string)
    print(mstring) #just for troubleshooting 
    stripped = mstring.group(1)
    print(stripped)
```

I don't understand quite a few things about this code.

The two if \ elif statements only check for the _strip argument if it's non-existent, a space or a symbol given in the respecchar list above the function. The guy claims the code works even if you put a letter as the second argument and nobody in the comment section even questions it. How come ?

The second thing I wanted to ask was about the line under the elif statement : strip = r''+_strip'
Doesn't the string end after the second quotation mark ( since it begins with only a single quotation mark ) ? How come the whole string ends only after the +_strip part of it ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

> The two if \ elif statements only check for the _strip argument if it's non-existent, a space or a symbol given in the respecchar list above the function. The guy claims the code works even if you put a letter as the second argument

That's because those characters are the only ones that need special handling in a regex.  If it's a plain letter, it can be used as part of the regex exactly as-is.

```
strip = r'\'+_strip'
```

That's a typo.  The trailing `'` shouldn't be there.

Comment: I don't understand that line though, could you explain it to me ? I see it as ''match the second argument in the given string if it's preceded by at least one slash symbol''. Apparently, it should be ''match a string containing a character from the symbol list defined above''.

Comment: _I don't understand that line though_ What line exactly?

Comment: Also, the function doesn't seem to strip the right character, only the left one.

Comment: Sorry, I understood the initial question now. The slash is necessary to escape any of the characters given in the last, though I don't understand why only one slash isn't the only acceptable option ( since the plus is given right after, alluding to the fact any number of slashes is fine for some reason ).

Comment: I still don't get why the function returns the string without only the first character, but includes the last one ( when the same character is in question ) regardless of what type of character I type in as the second argument.

Comment: The right character isn't stripped because the pattern ends with an asterisk, indicating that the final strip character is optional.  Regular expressions are _greedy_ by default, meaning that the `*(.+)` pattern will match as much as it can, so it matches up to the end of the string, leaving nothing to match as the final strip character.  I'm not sure why he did it that way.

Comment: I exchanged the asterisks with pluses and it works.

Comment: But also, I tried adding a question mark after the (.+) and leaving the asterisks, and it also works for some reason... ?

Comment: Thanks a ton anyway :)

Comment: That will fail if the pattern doesn't end with the strip char.

Comment: What will ? The plus replacement or the question mark ?

Comment: The plus.  Plus means it _must_ have the strip char at the end.

Comment: What does the question mark after the (.+ followed by ) do exactly then ? It's the non-greedy version, I get that, but how does it work really ?

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 as the `.` matches any character except newlines (well, whatever your wild-card character preferences are), and the `.+` matches 1 or more of the `.` character, the `?` in `.+?` makes it *optional*; none or 1 or more matches.